# Convert Website Project to Web Application Project via Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I just upgraded my visual studio from 2012 to version 2013. Now i am trying to convert my website project to web application project via visual studio 2013 which i normally done easily in previous versions. But there is no "Convert to Web Application" option when i right clicked on root folder.

Need help.